# Translation involving ∀x∀y∀z

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Domain of discourse: the set of human beings.

Exercise($x$) := $x$ enjoys exercising.

How does $$∀x∀y∀z ( (x ≠ y) ∧(y ≠ z) ∧(x ≠ z) \to (\text{Exercise}(x) ∧ \text{Exercise}(y) ∧ \text{Exercise}(z)) )$$ translate to natural English?

Comment: Ahhh please use proper MathJax...

Comment: @Nightflight John's a new contributor -- perhaps it would be more constructive to point them to a resource such as [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? You can also edit the question to teach by showing.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of clarity. Exercise(x) means that 'x' likes to exercise. The problem itself just wants to know how the statement would translate to natural english. I believe Exercise(x) itself is true, which means that 'x' indeed likes to go out and exercise.

Comment: "Every member of every group of three distinct humans enjoys exercising."  Welcome to the site. Since this forum encourages learning, in the future, please show your thoughts, ideas, and *attempt* at the problem, and please use mathjax (click on Edit above to see how I've reformatted your post). Here's a [quick guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) on how to ask a good Question, which is less likely to get closed/deleted and more likely to get a good Answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and advice!